# How to center several divs displayed with float left

Tags: css, html, center, css-float

I have the following:

```
<footer id="contentinfo" class="footer">
        <div class="networking_wrapper">
        <div style="float: left;"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/twitter.png")"/></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flicker.png")"/></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/facebook.png")"/></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/blog.png")"/></div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

How can I make .networking_wrapper to be centered on #contentinfo (which is a width 100% of the view because, as you can see, is the footer of the page).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

Just had to add `text-align:center;` to the `<footer>`
and set `.networking_wrapper` `display: inline-block`.

Hope it helps someone =)